# Click on Input Type=Image

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, applescript

I have to click on a button whose tag is `<input type="image"` and thus far, I haven't really figured out a great way to do this. I'm opposed to specifying coordinates, so programmatically is preferred.

**Here's the full tag:**

```
<input type="image" src="/eImages/button/next.gif" name="Next" border="0">
```

There's no other `<a>` or anything like that, so I'm not really sure what my other options are. I also couldn't find a form ID or anything.

**This is what I tried:**

```
do JavaScript "var elements = document.getElementsByName('Next');
for (i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
  if(elements[i].type == 'image') {
    click();
  }
}" in doc
```

By the way, this is an Applescript, scripting the browser using Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your "if" condition, write this:

```
elements[i].click();
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KryH3/2/

Answer (score 1):

Not qute shure what you need - but it seems all you're missing is that instead of `click()` you should put `elements[i].click()`.